# svn log --xml invalid xml

Tags: svn

I am using the `svn log --xml` response to look at the changes for a particular revision. But in case of an invalid revision or path, I want to just to get a blank but valid xml response. Is it possible to do that?

So instead of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
svn: Unable to find repository location for 'http://subversion.ny.jpmorgan.com /svn/repos/IM_RPS_CORE/rps_deploy_tools_content_test/branches/rol-201106-content-test' in revision 1556
```

I could get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
</log>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No can do.

However, if you check the exit status code of your `svn log` command, you can handle the issue yourself. For example, in a Bash shell script:

```
if ! svn log --xml $url > $xmlOutput 2> /dev/null
then
     cat > $xmlOutput <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
</log>
EOF
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the error code of the command and do not try to parse its output or generate an empty XML instead. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=svn_log.xml
svn log --xml > "${FILE}" 2>/dev/null
RET=$?

if [ $RET -ne 0 ]; then
(cat <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
</log>
EOF
) > "${FILE}"

fi

cat "${FILE}"
```